# Using firebase to bind data between Angular and Polymer

Tags: angularjs, firebase, polymer

I'm trying to make a working example using Firebase to sync data between an Angular app and Polymer on the same file. I'm using the [firebase-element from Polymer](https://github.com/Polymer/firebase-element)

Is it possible? I've have both apps in their own sections so Angular doesn't try to hijack Polymer's binding but I'm not getting data on the Polymer side or throwing any useful errors.

Appreciate any attention. Thank you. [Here's the Plnkr.](http://plnkr.co/edit/Hzq7oQrTY77eQomoirv0)

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <script data-require="polymer@*" data-semver="0.3.4" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/polymer/0.3.4/platform.js"></script>
    <script data-require="polymer@*" data-semver="0.3.4" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/polymer/0.3.4/polymer.js"></script>
    <script data-require="angular.js@*" data-semver="1.3.1" src="//code.angularjs.org/1.3.1/angular.js"></script>
    <script data-require="firebase@1.0.x" data-semver="1.0.18" src="https://cdn.firebase.com/js/client/1.0.18/firebase-debug.js"></script>
    <script data-require="angularfire@0.8.x" data-semver="0.8.0" src="https://cdn.firebase.com/libs/angularfire/0.8.0/angularfire.js"></script>
    <script data-require="firebase-simple-login@1.6.x" data-semver="1.6.2" src="https://cdn.firebase.com/js/simple-login/1.6.2/firebase-simple-login.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <link rel="import" href="firebase-element.html" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <section ng-app="component-angular">
      <div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
        <h2>Data in Angular</h2>
          {{data}}
        <h3>
          <input ng-model="new.data" placeholder="" />
          <button ng-click="addData(new.data)">Add New Data</button>
        </h3>
      </div>
    </section>
    <section>
      <div>
        <firebase-element id="base" location="https://tezt.firebaseio.com/web-components" data="{{data}}" keys="{{keys}}"></firebase-element>
        <h3>My Firebase Data</h3>
        <template repeat="{{key in keys}}">
            <p>{{key}}: {{data[key]}}</p>
        </template>
      </div>
    </section>

    <script>
      var app = angular.module('component-angular', ['firebase'])
      .controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $firebase, Firebase){
        var fb = new Firebase("https://tezt.firebaseio.com/web-components");
        var fbSync = $firebase(fb);
        $scope.data = fbSync.$asObject();
        $scope.addData = function(newData){
          fbSync.$push(newData);
        }
      });
    </script>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Angular and Polymer together seems a bit pointless, considering you can already create components, data bind, et al in Angular.

Comment: The main benefit is popping in quality components in existing angular apps.